# User History screen has a UI bug in Firefox/Gecko browsers

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

The "User History" screen moderator-tool has an interesting UI bug on Firefox with Linux. Haven't checked FF on other platforms, but it does do it on multiple FF/Linux machines of mine.

[image: User History screenshot]

First of all, compared to how the screen looks in Opera 11, the Date column is immediately after the [change filter] link, rather than on the next line. I can reproduce this in SeaMonkey 2.0 (another Mozilla browser, uses Gecko same as FF) on Windows. On IE8/Windows, it looks normal:

[image: Normal image is normal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If necessary, implementations should clear the said element by placing it below any preceding floats, but may place it adjacent to such floats if there is sufficient space.

<sup>[source](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats)</sup>

Looks like Gecko's definition of "sufficient space" differs from mine :)

There will be an additional `clear: both` in the next build, fixing this.