# Reporting bugs in moderator tools

Tags: discussion, moderator-tools, design, bug-reports

I've discovered a display bug in the private messaging tool over at [Android](http://android.stackexchange.com).

I was just going to post on the meta site over there so Jin could see it, but I don't know if screen shots of the tool are okay for public consumption. So, I'm asking here.

Is it okay/expected for bugs in moderator tools to be reported on public meta sites?

Comment: I usually just ping a developer in chat, or e-mail the team. There's some stuff that's probably safe if redacted as Fabian said, but you just never know. I think in this case, it's better to be safe than sorry. You can e-mail `team@stackoverflow` with the screen shots and a description. You won't get magic unicorn points for reporting the bug, but .. well .. you don't get magic unicorn points for anything else in the mod area either :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In addition to what Fabian said, you could always use Community ♦ as the user for your screenshots. There's no information there that's private (it's not a person), and you can still reproduce your bug, as it's still a user. For example:

[image]

Comment: Ah, good idea. I was going to use one of my fellow moderators, but using Community is a better idea.

Answer (score 4):

The tools themselves are not secret, the private data contained in them is. So I would say you can post bug reports publicly about the mod tools, as long as you remove any private data that would be visible.

For the private messaging tool that would mean not using a real private message that contains user information. For the flag list or the moderator overview you would have to edit the screenshots and blank out any sensitive information. It might be easier in some cases to just use a private channel for reporting those, then.

I remember a few bug reports with screenshots of mod tools (e.g. [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111325/moderator-nominations-are-showing-up-in-the-mod-queue) or [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78384/user-history-screen-has-a-ui-bug-in-firefox-gecko-browsers) or [this one from myself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106658/flag-count-discrepancy-in-moderator-history)), and I haven't seen any complaints about these.

The exception are the tools for detecting sock puppets or vote fraud, I don't think those should be revealed. Bug reports for those I'd make directly in the Teachers Lounge or via mail to the team.

Comment: Screenshots can also be edited to blur out or remove sensitive information.